# R data.table - interpolation

Tags: r, data.table

I have customer data, and prices

```
cust <- data.table(cust_id = c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8),
            product = c("A","B","A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
            cost = c(100000, 120000, 250000, 900000,909000,105000,101000,201000,792000,600000))        
prices <- data.table(product = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)),
                  bound = rep(c(100000, 150000, 200000, 500000, 1000000),2),
                  price_bound = c(1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 2, 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 2))
```

I want to produce an output that looks like

```
cust_id product cost     bound_lo price_bound_lo bound_hi price_bound_hi
1       A       100000   100000   1.2             150000   1.3
1       B       120000   100000   1.0             150000   1.1
2       A       250000   200000   1.4             500000   1.5
3       A       900000   500000   1.5            1000000   2.0
3       B       909000   500000   1.5            1000000   2.0
4       B       105000   100000   1.0             150000   1.1
5       B       101000   100000   1.0             150000   1.1    
6       B       201000   200000   1.3             500000   1.5
7       B       792000   500000   1.5            1000000   2.0
8       B       600000   500000   1.5            1000000   2.0
```

which will allow me to interpolate between the bounds.
My first thought was to use the `data.table` package because of its speed, as well as the ability to do rolling joins, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to code it.

UPDATE

The code

```
cust[prices, `:=` ("bound_lo" = i.bound, "price_bound_lo" = i.price_bound), on = c("product==product","cost>=bound")]
```

correctly produces the lower bounds, but I'm still having trouble making the (lowest) upper bound work

Comment: Why is `bound_hi` not `150000` for the first row?

Comment: corrected the mistake - should be accurate now

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach using non-equi joins:

```
library(data.table)

#create a table of lower and upper bounds
prng <- prices[, .(lb=bound[-.N], ub=bound[-1L], lp=price_bound[-.N], up=price_bound[-1L]), 
    by=.(product)]

#perform non-equi join and extract relevant columns
prng[cust, .(cust_id=i.cust_id, product=i.product, cost=i.cost,
        bound_lo=lb, price_bound_lo=lp, bound_hi=ub, price_bound_hi=up), 
    by=.EACHI, on=.(product=product, lb<=cost, ub>=cost)][, -(1L:3L)]
```

output:

```
    cust_id product   cost bound_lo price_bound_lo bound_hi price_bound_hi
 1:       1       A 100000    1e+05            1.2   150000            1.3
 2:       1       B 120000    1e+05            1.0   150000            1.1
 3:       2       A 250000    2e+05            1.4   500000            1.5
 4:       3       A 900000    5e+05            1.5  1000000            2.0
 5:       3       B 909000    5e+05            1.5  1000000            2.0
 6:       4       B 105000    1e+05            1.0   150000            1.1
 7:       5       B 101000    1e+05            1.0   150000            1.1
 8:       6       B 201000    2e+05            1.3   500000            1.5
 9:       7       B 792000    5e+05            1.5  1000000            2.0
10:       8       B 600000    5e+05            1.5  1000000            2.0
```

Comment: I understand that `1L` and `.N` return the first and last value in the `by` group respectively, but can you explain how `-1L` and `-.N` work

Comment: Negative indexing means exclude those indices

Answer (score 0):

I would create a reference table and join the result to the cust table.

This is how I'd do it:

```
library(dplyr)

cust <- data.table(cust_id = c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                  product = c("A","B","A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                  cost = c(100000, 120000, 250000, 
                  900000,909000,105000,101000,201000,
                  792000,600000))        

prices_final <- data.table(product = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)),
                     bound = rep(c(100000, 150000, 200000, 
                     500000, 1000000, 90000, 80000, 
                     70000, 50000, 135000),),
                     price_bound = c(1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 2, 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 2)) %>%
  mutate(bound_lo = format(ave(bound, product, FUN = min), 
                           scientific = FALSE),
         bound_hi = format(ave(bound, product, FUN = max), 
                           scientific = FALSE),
         price_hi = ave(price_bound, product, FUN = max),
         price_lo = ave(price_bound, product, FUN = min))

prices_final <- prices_final[,-c('bound', 'price_bound')]
prices_final <- unique(prices_final)

prices_final <- left_join(cust, prices_final, by='product')
```